# Must a square root of a diagonal matrix with distinct eigenvalues be diagonal?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $D$ be the diagonal matrix and $A^2=D$

So far I've taken 2 approaches, the first being a direct algebraic approach. For a $2 \times 2$ matrix  this reduces to $$  \left( \begin{matrix}
    a_{11} & a_{12}  \\
    a_{21} & a_{22}  \\ 
   \end{matrix} \right )^2 = 
\left( \begin{matrix}
    a_{11}^2 +a_{21}a_{12} & a_{12}(a_{11} + a_{22})  \\
    a_{21}(a_{11} + a_{22}) & a_{22}^2 +a_{21}a_{12}  \\ 
   \end{matrix} \right ) =
\left( \begin{matrix}
    d_1 & 0  \\
    0 & d_2  \\ 
   \end{matrix} \right )$$ where $d_1 \ne d_2$.

From the top right and bottom left squares it's easy to see that $a_{12}=a_{21}=0$ or $a_{11} +a_{22}=0$

If $a_{12}=a_{21}=0$ then, $$d_1=a_{11}^2 +a_{21}a_{12}=a_{22}^2 +a_{21}a_{12}=d_2$$ which means the eigenvalues aren't distinct. Thus $A$ is diagonal.

This proves it when $A$ is $2 \times 2 $.

For  $n \times n $ $A$, with $n$ linearly independent eigenvectors $\mathbf v_1 , ..., \mathbf v_n$ with corresponding eigenvalues $ \lambda_1 , ... , \lambda_n$ such that for $j \ne k$  $ \lambda^2_j \ne \lambda^2_k$
Now $$ D \mathbf v_k =A^2 \mathbf v_k= \lambda^2_k \mathbf v_k$$

thus $\lambda_k^2$ is and eigenvalue of $D$ and $\mathbf v_k$ is the corresponding basis vector, hence the eigenvectors of $A$ are just the standard basis vectors and hence $A$ is diagonal

Is my conjecture that a square root of a diagonal matrix with distinct eigenvalues is diagonal wrong or is there a general proof?

Comment: Over $ \Bbb R$?

Comment: Over $\Bbb C$  would be the most familar.

Comment: @ Brevan Ellefsen Are those the only square roots though?

Comment: @B.Martin I had your post while in a hurry. Forgive me. Deleted my comment

Comment: All cool man.  _

Comment: What happened to the case $a_{11}+a_{22}=0$?

Comment: @GerryMyerson When $a_{11}=-a_{22}$ you can sub it in to get $d_1=d_2$ which directly contradicts the assumption that $D$ has distinct eigenvalues

Comment: OK, but that has to be in your post. No matter, now that the question's been closed as a duplicate.